Manga about a thief who is transmigrated and becomes a beast tamer
A female thief gets transmigrated into an ancient Chinese world and becomes a rank 9 beast tamer who tames an ice phoenix. There is also a prince who tamed a horse covered in people flames.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?
